# Problemas com o GCC no Windows 10

Tags: c, visual-studio, ide, gcc

Estou enfrentando problemas ao mudar de IDE, me disseram que o DEVC++ contém muito bugs e por opção também já estava afim de experimentar outras IDE's, resolvi então testar o Code::Blocks e o Visual Studio Code, porém em ambas dão problema quando vou executar meu código, exemplo do que aparece no Visual Studio:

> 'gcc' nao � reconhecido como um comando interno
>   ou externo, um programa oper�vel ou um arquivo em lotes.

Comment: Para utilizar o gcc no Microsoft Windows você precisa utilizar o MinGW. http://mingw.org/

Comment: Obrigado @anonimo estava faltando eu instalar isso ai também, pensava que por já ter o Dev C++ e algumas IDE's achei que o GCC também já estaria instalado no meu PC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verifique se a variável de ambiente PATH no Windows contém o caminho mingw \ bin

```
set PATH=C:\MinGW\bin;%PATH%
```

Certificando se ocorreu tudo certo:

```
digitar gcc -v
```

Caso não der certo o primeiro comando, tente esse (encontrando a váriavel)

```
set path | findstr /I /C:"mingw"
```

Depois verifique novamente:

```
digitar gcc -v
```

Comment: Após isso ele deverá reabrir a janela de console, e se mesmo assim não funcionar, reiniciar o computador.

Comment: @CypherPotato exato, precisei reiniciar o computador

Comment: Obrigado a todos ae, fiz os testes e deu certinho e até consegui rodar uns códigos que fiz hehe